# ¿Cómo validar una varible indefinidad JQUERY?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Estoy enviando unos parametros por [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) a [php](/questions/tagged/php) y este me responde por medio de [json](/questions/tagged/json) varias respuestas, ya que en la funcion del php se encuentran varias peticiones al modelo para traer un `count` por sentencia [sql](/questions/tagged/sql).

El problema esta en que la respuesta del [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) si hay un dato vacío lo declara como indefinida.

y la idea es que me cargue esos `count` por variable en boton con `badge`.

**CODIGO JS**

```
$('#Competencias').change(function(event) 
{   
    IdCompetencia = $(this).val();

    var cadena = {'IdPeriodo' : IdPeriodo};
    cadena.IdSede = IdSede,
    cadena.AreaEmpleado = AreaEmpleado,
    cadena.IdCompetencia  = IdCompetencia,

    $.post('EscalaCualitativaEmpleados', cadena , function(data) 
    {
        var resultado = $.parseJSON(data);

        console.info(resultado.rendimientoalto[0]['rendimiento_alto'] );
        if(typeof(resultado.rendimientobajo[0]['rendimiento_bajo'] === 'undefined') && typeof(resultado.rendimientomedio[0]['rendimiento_medio'] === 'undefined') && typeof(resultado.rendimientoalto[0]['rendimiento_alto'] === 'undefined'))
        {
            $('#oculto').fadeIn("slow");
            $('#CountResultCompetenciaButtons').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Bajo <span class="badge">0</span></button>' 
                                                    + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Medio <span class="badge">0</span></button>'
                                                        +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Alto <span class="badge">0</span></button>');
        }

        else if(typeof(resultado.rendimientobajo[0]['rendimiento_bajo'] === 'undefined') &&  typeof(resultado.rendimientomedio[0]['rendimiento_medio'] === 'undefined'))
        {
            $('#oculto').fadeIn("slow");
            $('#CountResultCompetenciaButtons').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Bajo <span class="badge">0</span></button>' 
                                                    + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Medio <span class="badge">0</span></button>'
                                                        +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Alto <span class="badge">' + resultado.rendimientoalto[0]['rendimiento_alto']['rendimiento_alto'] + '</span></button>');
        }

        else if(typeof(resultado.rendimientomedio[0]['rendimiento_medio'] === 'undefined') && typeof(resultado.rendimientoalto[0]['rendimiento_alto'] === 'undefined'))
        {
            $('#oculto').fadeIn("slow");
            $('#CountResultCompetenciaButtons').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Bajo <span class="badge">' + resultado.rendimientobajo[0]['rendimiento_bajo']['rendimiento_bajo'] + '</span></button>' 
                                                    + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Medio <span class="badge">0</span></button>'
                                                        +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Alto <span class="badge">0</span></button>');
        }

        else if(typeof(resultado.rendimientoalto[0]['rendimiento_alto'] === 'undefined') && typeof(resultado.rendimientobajo[0]['rendimiento_bajo'] === 'undefined'))
        {
            $('#oculto').fadeIn("slow");
            $('#CountResultCompetenciaButtons').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Bajo <span class="badge">0</span></button>' 
                                                    + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Medio <span class="badge">' + resultado.rendimientomedio[0]['rendimiento_medio']['rendimiento_medio'] + '</span></button>'
                                                        +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Alto <span class="badge">0</span></button>');
        }

        else
        {
            $('#oculto').fadeIn("slow");
            $('#CountResultCompetenciaButtons').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Bajo <span class="badge">' + resultado.rendimientobajo[0]['rendimiento_bajo']['rendimiento_bajo'] + '</span></button>' 
                                                    + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Medio <span class="badge">' + resultado.rendimientomedio[0]['rendimiento_medio']['rendimiento_medio'] + '</span></button>'
                                                        +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">Alto <span class="badge">' + resultado.rendimientoalto[0]['rendimiento_alto']['rendimiento_alto'] + '</span></button>');
        }           
    });
```

**ERROR**

> ```
> prueba.js:171 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendimiento_bajo' of undefined
>     at Object.success (prueba.js:171)
>     at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
>     at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
>     at k (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
> ```

Comment: ¿ Podrías mostrar una de esas respuestas que te genera problemas ? La cadena JSON.

Comment: Object {rendimientobajo: Array(1), rendimientomedio: Array(0), rendimientoalto: Array(1)}

Answer (score 2):

Lo que tienes `undefined` es **el contenido del array**, no el array en sí. Lógico, puesto que **está vacío**.

Usa la propiedad `length` para comprobar la **longitud** del array que recibes:

```
if( resultado.rendimientobajo.length )
// No está vacío
{
  ...
}

if( resultado.rendimientomedio.length )
// No está vacío
{
  ...
}

...
```

`Object#length` devuelve la **longitud** del elemento. Los caracteres, si es una cadena. **El número de elementos**, si es un *array*.

Dará resultados *curiosos* si el *array* no tiene todos los índices *consecutivos*; en realidad, `length` devuelve el **mayor índice usado** del array. Pero, tal y como lo estás usando, en un objeto obtenido al *parsear* un JSON, no tendrás problemas.

Comment: @lois6b Te he esperado. Un rato.

Comment: oh vaya, no note que fueras a escribir y por ello esperarme. perdona.

Comment: @lois6b no suelo entrar en Javascript, pero es que estaba aburrido ;-) Recupera la tuya y borro esta. No importa. Te perdono el *in-itinere*

Comment: nonono Hahaha pero buen latinismo ^^

Answer (score 1):

Puedes comprobar directamente si cada array es nulo de la siguiente forma:

```
if (typeof resultado.rendimientobajo === "undefined") {
// Hacer algo...
}
```